# How to convert a list to nested list in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a List object

```
List<string> intList = new List<string>();
```

I have a,b,c,d,e,f in "intList" object. Normally, HTML render is

```
<ul>
  <li>a<li>
  <li>b<li>
  <li>c<li>
  <li>d<li> 
  <li>e<li>
  <li>f<li>
</ul>
```

Above one: I can easily render HTML in MVC view page:

```
<ul>
   @foreach(var item in Model)
   {
      <li>@item</li>
   }
</ul>
```

The following a carousel HTML one is difficult render like above code.
Any suggestions?

```
<div id="carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <ul>
      <li>a<li>
      <li>b<li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <ul>
      <li>c<li>
      <li>d<li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <ul>
      <li>e<li>
      <li>f<li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Difficult to render? Not at all. Maybe provide more information on what you're actually having problems with??

Comment: just place an i outside the loop. increment it on each iteration. write extra logic on `i % 2 ==0`

Comment: @walther:  sorry to confuse you. The question how to render carousel html format from a list /

Comment: That's all nice and dandy, just not sure what's your exact problem and what have you tried that didn't work as expected. This is a simple C# for-loop...

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
<div class="item>
    <ul>
       @foreach(var item in Model)
       {
          if(item % 2 == 0)
          {
              </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="item>
              <ul>  
          }
          <li>@item</li>
       }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated the questions. I used numbers as an example to ask clear question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard for loop and check if the loop variable is `> 0` and if it is divisible by 2:

```
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
<div class="item">
    <ul>
       @for(int i =0; i<Model.Count; i++)
       {
          if(i> 0 && i % 2 == 0)
          {
              @:</ul>
              @:</div>
              @:<div class="item">
              @:<ul>  
          }
          <li>@Model[i]</li>
       }
    </ul>
</div>
}
```